# Get Selected Index

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

Boa tarde. quero setar a opção de um campo JComboBox como sendo a opção cadastrada em uma determinada posição de um vetor. 
Para um campo de texto anterior, fiz a seguinte configuração:

```
campoCpf.setText(vetAluno[i].getCpf());
```

Para setar o JComboBox, como eu chamaria a opção selecionada do vetor, supondo, por exemplo, 3 opções, se eu selecionei uma delas e o cadastro foi gravado como sendo aquela opção escolhida, como chamar?

Eu sei que devo setar o campo assim:

```
campoCurso.setSelectedIndex();
```

mas qual parametro devo passar?

Comment: Você tem uma variável e quer que o `JComboBox` selecione a posição que tem o valor dessa variável, é isso?

Answer (score 0):

Basta você passar o objeto que deseja selecionar dentro do método `setSelectedItem`.

Dessa forma:

```java
String [] s = {"orange", "pear", "apple", "banana"};

JComboBox test = new JComboBox(s);
test.setSelectedItem("banana");
```

O método `setSelectedIndex`, que você citou, seleciona pela posição no vetor. Se quiséssemos selecionar `banana` usando ele, ficaria assim:

```java
String [] s = {"orange", "pear", "apple", "banana"};

JComboBox test = new JComboBox(s);
test.setSelectedIndex(3);
```